# matplotlib contour involving natural log

Tags: python, numpy, math, matplotlib, statistics

I am trying to plot a contour,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X, Y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-1.0, 1.0, 100), np.linspace(-1.0, 1.0, 100))

C = np.log(1 - ((X - 0.2)**2 + (Y - 0.2)**2)**0.5) 

plt.contour(X,Y,C,[0])
plt.show()
```

However since the log argument goes negative, this seems to get in the way of plotting.

The unit circle

```
F = X**2 + Y**2 - 1
plt.contour(X,Y,F,[0])
```

plots fine.

How do I plot a function C, which has a logarithm involving X and Y?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem with the math, not with plotting. The function you have has a single zero point at (0.2,0.2). You cannot draw a line through a single point.

If you wanted to show the contour at  `-1` for example, this works as expected,

```
plt.contour(X,Y,C,[-1])
```

[image]